# is using the lon/lat to street address conversion of google maps API limited by number of queries?

Tags: android, json, google-maps

is using the URLs such as this http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=true limited by number of queries?

I am asking because I know that GOOGLEs api for location has limited queries.
So, if I know the longitude and latitude, am-I allowed to convert it to a street address as many times as I wish using this URL? 
Thanks in advance for response :)

Comment: "convert it to a street address as many times as I wish" ... Are you concerned that the street address will change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is known as "Reverse geocoding", there is quota management on it.

Users of the standard API:

- 2,500 free requests per day
- 10 requests per second
- $0.50 USD / 1000 additional requests, up to 100,000 daily.

You should (must) also include your API key in the request.

References:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

Answer (score 1):

Every request to http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/* is subject to Google Maps Geocode API limits: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits. Consider caching your results, if you expect geocoding the same locations. Before doing that though, read up on [Geocoding Strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#caching) (section **Caching Considerations**) to make sure you don't violate the API's terms of service.